# Attempt to upload to s3 on backend and frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, mongoose, flutter

I have a slight problem which i have been attempting to solve for several hours, however found no success in doing so.

I require to upload to s3 (for a users profile pic). I successfully do so on the backend.

I then store the url as a string in the database(as the users profile pic property)

However, the issue comes here. I am using flutter on the frontend, and need to to do the following.

Make a http request to the upload url and can do successfully. But i don't know a method to do the following:

- Allow a user to select a photo from camera roll for the request. In node the users selects a file by req.files.file, which gets uploaded to s3. How would i turn the req.files.file(what file user picks to upload) into a file the user picks from the camera roll. Thats my only issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dependency for image picker:

> import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

The way I am doing it is by converting the file to base64 and then bytes followed by decoding it in the backend and then uploading to s3 from there.

```
uploadImage() async {
  var _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
    sourcePath: _image.path,
    ratioX: 1.0,
    ratioY: 1.0,
    maxWidth: 512,
    maxHeight: 512,
  );

  var _params = {
    "image_file": base64Encode(croppedFile.readAsBytesSync()),
  };

  return await restCall(POST, apiUrl.uploadImage, _params);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot man. One thing is how would i tell flutter that req.files.file  (from node) is the croppedFile?

Comment: I use this dependency to crop my image: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_cropper

Comment: Oh nice. How do i tell flutter that on the backend the req.files.file is equal to the image the user selects. And thank you for your answer bro.

Comment: On the backend you will receive the image in a base64 string like any other post string key and value parameter. Once you receive it, decode the base64 and then decode the bytes into a File and you can then upload that to s3.

Comment: If i had a post request endpoint. Lets say i had a parameter like username. In flutter how would i send a post request with them values set. E.g username to a text field?

Comment: Basically how do you set post parameters friend?

Comment: Make another question for that, that needs a detailed answer. You can easily google it. You need to store the textFormField value to a variable and then pass that variable in your parameter before calling the post request.

Comment: Thank you.But in your params what does "image_file" stand for. Is it in the backend or something, and how does it works. Thanks once again bro.

Comment: Ah nice, but i dont understand. In the backend how do you declare a "key" to be set?

Comment: Where does this key come from?